# Twython - Twitter API returned a 401

Tags: python, twitter, twython

First time using Twython and following an example found in the docs [here](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/advanced_usage.html).

```
from twython import Twython



APP_KEY='my_key'
APP_SECRET='my_secret'
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens()

OAUTH_TOKEN=auth['oauth_token']
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET=auth['oauth_token_secret']

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)


results = twitter.cursor(twitter.search, q='BarackObama')
for result in results:
    print result
```

I am getting the following back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/%USER%/PycharmProjects/WebGatherBusiness/twitter_experiments.py", line 26, in <module>
    for result in results:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 478, in cursor
    content = function(**params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twython/endpoints.py", line 230, in search
    return self.get('search/tweets', params=params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 264, in get
    return self.request(endpoint, params=params, version=version)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 258, in request
    api_call=url)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twython/api.py", line 194, in _request
    retry_after=response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Reset'))
twython.exceptions.TwythonAuthError: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Invalid or expired token.
```

Could someone please provide some guidance?

Thank you!

Comment: ah - i should be using the keys on `apps.twitter.com` not the one generated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the keys on apps.twitter.com not the one generated via `get_authentication_tokens`